# Bound for the number of solutions of a polynomial system of equation.

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

Given integers $d_1,\ldots,d_n$, is there an elementary way to justify that for generic polynomials $f_1,\ldots,f_n\in\mathbb{C}[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ of degree less or equal than $d_1,\ldots,d_n$, the number of solutions of $f_1=\cdots=f_n=0$ is bounded by some constant $C(d_1,\ldots,d_n)$?

Explicit bound is given by [Berstein's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/481261/generalization-of-bezout-theorem-in-higher-dimension/484079#484079) for example, but I am interested by more basic argument.

Comment: It would be even better to explain that the number of solutions is constant.

Comment: Going to the projective space and using intersection number is in my opinion the simplest way. A more basic argument could be the use of resultants in several variables. But basic doesn't mean simpler...